# javascript bigint conversion

Tags: javascript, bigint

To represent balance as u128, we assume that the smallest decimal is 15. i.e the smallest unit is  1e-15. Now, I need the following functionalities:

(1) convert between float to big number integer e.g. 0.001$ is 0.001*1e15=1e12 as bignumber integer.

(2) convert the balance into byte array, either big endian or small endian, so that I can sign on it.

The library I used before is "bn.js". It supports (2), however, if I want to convert 1000$ as bigint by using:

```
let amt = new BN(1e18, 10)
```

I will get error, because bn.js requires the number to be less than 2^53, but 1e18>2^53. This is just against the point of big number! Here is the link to this restriction:
https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/blob/master/lib/bn.js#L128

There are some other libraries such as bignumber.js I check, but they doesn't support (2).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt — JS has native support for BigInts now.

Comment: Be aware that Safari has limited support for BigInt, namely with respect to DataView - at least according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this GitHub repo: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/

```
let amt = bigInt("1e18");
```

or you can use a different base:

```
let largeHexValue = bigInt("FFFFF",16)
```

Comment: Does it support byte array conversion?